# What language is Google Sky Map coded in?

Tags: web-applications, graphics

I would like to create a Google Sky Map-kinda application for Ubuntu.

I was going to use WebGL and the Ubuntu Touch IDE, but I don't really know what Google Sky Map uses...

I have been unable to find out, so I have a few questions:

- What language is Google Sky Map coded in?
- Does it use OpenGL?
- How does the app create the link between the coordinates of a person and what is visible in the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google Sky](http://www.google.com/sky/) has a front-end written in Javascript and seems to work like Google Maps with tiled images. I'm not sure if that's the one you mean. There is also [Google Sky Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.stardroid&hl=en), an Android app, which is written in Java. It is [open-source](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2012/01/open-sourcing-sky-map-and-collaborating.html), and you can [look at the code here](https://code.google.com/p/stardroid/source/browse).

It does look like it uses OpenGL, I see a lot of `import android.opengl` and `import javax.microedition.khronos` in the code.

This app uses [android.location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html) to match up the user's location to its data. Check out the file `app/src/com/google/android/stardroid/control/LocationController.java` in the source for more details on how Sky Map does this.